# Cannot create an instance of Usercontrol when subscribing an event

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

There are other threads on the topic but I did not find any that are related to my specific problem.

In Visual Studio 2017, I have a situation when the XAML designer prompt an error even though nothing strange seems to be present.

Basically, to reproduce the problem, consider those two files,

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Background="White">
            <TabItem Header="TEST" Width="60">
                <local:UserControl1/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Usercontrol1.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            App.Current.MainWindow.Closing += window_Closing;
        }

        void window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Note that I did not include the content of Usercontrol1.xaml because it is not relevant here. It can be an empty UserControl.

Now, the designer shows the Error

```
Cannot create an instance of "Usercontrol1".
```

It is strange since when starting the application, everything is working fine. This is easily reproducible by creating a new WPF app and creating the same pattern shown above.

**NOTE**

I tried removing the subscription

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Closing += window_Closing;
```

And it removes the error. So, it is the cause, but why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App.Current` will be null while in *DesignMode*.

You can check for *IsInDesignMode* to prevent running this code. Like,

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if(!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        App.Current.MainWindow.Closing += window_Closing;
}
```

Related post in [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jnak/2007/09/24/dealing-with-application-current-in-design-mode/).

Comment: Wow, that's a nice catch. Thanks a lot.